# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3 and want to append api_token as query string to student/dashboard url when login page is submitted as follows:

http://localhost/Exams/student/dashboard?api_token=4ZtxTu7fAwYpcPYRu46GWmVfncPO0i

But it always throw MethodNotAllowedException whenever postSudentLogin method is called. It shows correct url in address bar, but always throws 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218'.

Following is my code:
Login.blade.php:

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" id="post_req" role="form" name="User" method="post" action="{{ url('student/dashboard') }}" >

              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">                        
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My LoginController.php is:

```
     public function postStudentLogin(){         
        $student =  DB::table('students')->where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();
        if(Hash::check( Input::get('password'),$student->password)){
          Session::flash('login_message','You have been logged in successfully.');        
          // return view('student.dashboard');            
          return redirect()->route('dashboard',['api_token'=> $student->api_token]);                
        }
        else{                             
          return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Incorrect username/password');
        }               
    }
```

routes\web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'student', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function(){
   Route::get('/','Student\LoginController@getStudentHome');    
   Route::get('/login/{page}',['uses' => 'Student\LoginController@getStudentLogin' ]);  
   Route::post('/dashboard',['uses' =>'Student\LoginController@postStudentLogin'])->name('dashboard');      
});
```

Please guide me where I'm wrong. I'm stuck here.

Thanks,
Dipti Sheth

Comment: What is the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: instead of Route::post use Route::any because your url contain some query string so in route post method query string is not allowed please try Route::any

Comment: | Domain | Method   | URI                       | Name      | Action
                                                     | Middleware   |
-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST     | student/dashboard         | dashboard | App\Http\Controlle
rs\Auth\Student\LoginController@postStudentLogin     | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | student/login/{page}      |           | App\Http\Controlle
rs\Auth\Student\LoginController@getStudentLogin      | web,guest    |

Comment: @sunilwananje : hey...thanks...Route::any works, but it throws following error:  Trying to get property of non-object. It gives  array('student' => null)

Comment: Check your query its not showing result it means given email id is not in database so you have to handel this error

Comment: @sunilwananje: if I check it with dd($student), it shows me complete student details.

Comment: @sunilwananje: It throws error at following line: if(Hash::check( Input::get('password'),$student->password)){ }..........but before that If I put dd($student) it shows details

Comment: what comes in dd($student->password)

Comment: it gives password value, but when I try to  $pwd =$student->password; it again throws same error: Trying to get property of non-object 'student' = null . That's really weird.

Comment: Please share your dd($student) output...

Comment: @sunilwananje: my dd($student) output is: {#199 ▼
  +"id": 27
  +"email": "student@gmail.com"
  +"password": "$2y$10$pu3JMwmCBOAtA5bg05mrl.weMQ1/VNEZ2TSi2Gye5pWLzcrJc1.aO"
  +"api_token": "4ZtxTu7fAwYpcPYRu46GWmVfncPO0iHzee7NxKqNaY1a9907BoxT1iHl2Azi"
  +"name": "student"
  +"address": "pune"
  +"phone": "6545678932"  
  +"status": "Active"
  +"reg_code": "0"
  +"reg_status": "Live"
  +"expiry_days": 0
  +"renewal_date": null
  +"presetcode": null
  +"created_at": "2017-02-08 11:20:44"
  +"updated_at": "2017-02-08 11:20:44"
  +"last_login": null
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135825/discussion-between-sunilwananje-and-dipti-sheth).